# fPIC: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I'm installing lenstool on a 11.10 ubuntu computer. I already have installed it on my 12.04 laptop and , although after a lot of struggling, it worked. But this time I am getting a weird error. First I run ./configure and then I should run make. When I do that it runs to some point and then returns a couple of a errors just like this. and of course it doesn't install:

> fPIC -w -O3 -fno-automatic -finit-local-zero --fixed-line-length-none   -c -o histogram.o histogram.f
>   /bin/bash: fPIC: command not found
>
> make[1]: [histogram.o] Error 127 (ignored)

I'm not sure if it's relevant but on this machine I have gcc 4.6.1 and 4.4.6( I tryed setting both as the default compiler, neither worked ) but on my laptop I have 4.6.3

Thank you

EDIT:

I'm not sure what the problem was but I searched and found the makefile that was returning the error and replaced it with the one that worked on my laptop and it compiled.

Comment: What is `lenstool`? Please provide a link to the source you're trying to compile here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fPIC` is a compiler flag, not a command. It looks like the compiler specified in the Makefile does not exist. Often Makefiles will have a line defining the compiler in a variable, e.g.:

```
CC = gcc
```

The variable is then called with the compile flags to compile the program, if the variable is unset BASH will try and execute the flag itself:

```
$CC -fPIC source.c
```

Will be resolved by BASH  to:

```
-fPIC source.c
```

Which will give the error you see. Check the definition of the compiler in the Makefile.